# Node-Sass 4.9 modules installing issue on Node 10.2

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I get an issue when installing `node-sass` on my server (Ubuntu 16.04). On my local server I haven't theses errors...

NodeJS version : v10.2.1

Npm version : 5.6.0

Node sass version : ^4.9.0

**Error message :**

```
****@web-test:/var/www/****$ sudo npm i node-sass

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:872:3)
    at sync (/var/www/****/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/var/www/****/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/****/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN ****@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/****/.npm/_logs/2018-06-04T14_54_18_635Z-debug.log
```

**Permissions on the folder :** `drwxr-xr-x 11 root     root         4096 june   4 17:25 ****`

**Error after updating rights :**

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stackbcrypt_lib.target.mk:97: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/****/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/****/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/var/www/****/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
npm WARN ****@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Right solution (after many searches) :**

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: Apparently, the user used to run `npm install` has no access to the folder `/var/www`. Did you check that?

Comment: Ok so how can I check that ? When executing `cd /var/www` with the current user I have no error messages.

Comment: Try to run `sudo npm install`. If it works, check your user's rights for that folder.

Comment: As you can see to install `node-sass` I'm using `sudo npm install node-sass`, so I'm already using the `sudo` command, and I get the error too.

Comment: Check if you have permissions with your user to write into `'/var/www/****/` (ls -la). Anyway, it's clearly not a good practice to install your deps in sudo mode. Try to remove everything from that folder `'/var/www/****/` and especially the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again (not with sudo). Try `npm cache --clean` before to do that.

Comment: Another good resource to find a solution: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.

Comment: See permissions in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `root` user is the only one who has access to the `/www/var` folder. It would be better to create a dedicated user for that.

First of all, check with which user you're currently logged in with the following command:

```
$ whoami
```

And update the permissions of your destination folder for that user:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/[YOUR FOLDER]
```

And finally run `npm install` again.

Comment: It is better but I get a new error message. You can see the error in my edit just above.

Comment: I've found the solution. You can see the entire commands in my post.